# Scala method toLowerCase in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val file = sc.textFile(filePath)
val sol1=file.map(x=>x.split("\t")).map(x=>Array(x(4),x(5),x(1)))
val sol2=sol1.map(x=>x(2).toLowerCase)
```

In sol1, I have created an Rdd[Array[String]] and I want to put for every array the 3rd string element in LowerCase so call the method toLowerCase which should do that but instead it transform the string in lowercase char??

Comment: What do you mean "but instead it transform the string in lowercase char"? What else should it do? Perhaps show an example of expected vs. actual result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you want to convert 3rd array element to lower case

```
val sol1=file.map(x=>x.split("\t"))
             .map(x => Array(x(4),x(5),x(1).toLowerCase))
```

In your code, sol2 will be the sequence of string, not the sequence of array.